# Clojure fn name leaking outside its scope when compiled ahead-of-time

Tags: recursion, clojure, stack-overflow

I want to generate named functions with fn and return them from the macro, I tried the following example:

```
(defmacro getfn
  [namestr children]
  `(fn fn-name# []
     (println "Recursing" ~namestr)
     (doall (map (fn [child#] (child#)) ~children))))

(def foo (getfn "foo" []))
(def bar (getfn "bar" [foo]))

(defn -main [& args]
  (bar))
```

The resulting output is usually as expected:

```
Recursing bar
Recursing foo
```

However, when I run this compiled ahead-of-time (AOT) I get:

```
Recursing bar
Recursing bar
...
Recursing bar
Recursing bar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I find it pretty strange that bar keeps calling itself instead of foo, the only sensible reason for this is for the generated symbol `fn-name#` to leak outside its scope. Is this a bug in Clojure or intended behaviour?

**Update:** For clarity should mention that removing the `fn-name#` symbol and making the function anonymous fixes this problem. However, in my actual code I need to call it recursively sometimes, so naming it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I have for this problem is to use gensym to get a new symbol for each version of the macro, this would work by modifying the getfn as follows:

```
(defmacro getfn
  [namestr children]
  `(let [fn-name# (gensym)]
     (fn fn-name# []
       (println "Recursing" ~namestr)
       (doall (map (fn [child#] (child#)) ~children)))))
```

This feels a bit unnecessary since by definition the fn name should be relevant only inside its own scope.

**Update:** Just tested with alpha releases and it seems Clojure 1.7.0-alpha3 and later work without this hack, Clojure 1.7.0-alpha2 and earlier are broken. Using this workaround is probably ok until stable version of 1.7.0 is released, unless someone can think of something better.